# Litlle problem with integration API -> php

Tags: php, python, api, curl

I have this code in python that do a request to the API of suap passing the values of dados_usuario, that I tested and is working, but I wanna write the same code in php and I dont getting it, all I got was the token with the follow code, so, anyone could help me with the second part using curl in php?

python code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmgJM.jpg

```
import requests

# Obtaining the user's token
    url = 'https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/v2/autenticacao/token/'

#username and password are your data used to access SUAP
    dados_usuario = {
    'username': '',
    'password': ''
    }

    requisicao = requests.post(url, data=dados_usuario)
    if requisicao.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
      token_autenticacao = requisicao.json().get('token')
      print ('\n--- Token de Autenticação:\n {}\n\n'.format(token_autenticacao))

# Obtaining User Data.
    url = 'https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/v2/minhas-informacoes/meus-dados/'
    headers = {
     'Authorization':'JWT {}'.format(token_autenticacao)
    }
    requisicao = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if requisicao.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
     retorno_json = requisicao.json()
     print ('--- Dados do Usuário Logado:\n{}\n\n'.format(retorno_json))
```

php code - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH6eS.jpg

```
<?php

     $url = 'https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/v2/autenticacao/token/';

     $user_data = [
      'username' => '',
      'password' => ''
     ];

     $ch = curl_init();

 //Getting the user token

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_data);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
 //Token variable
     $token = json_decode($result, true);
     curl_close($ch);

     echo $token["token"]."\n\n";
```

I need get the user date with php, until now I just have the token, and I need get it with curl.

Comment: Code _inside_ the question please and as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolver with this code

```
$token = "token hide";
$ch = curl_init('https://suap.ifrn.edu.br/api/v2/minhas-informacoes/meus-dados/');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: JWT ' . $token
   ));

 $data = curl_exec($ch);

 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

 curl_close($ch);
```